# Implementing RaiseCanExecuteChanged method inside setter of a class object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, delegatecommand

I am still not sure if my approach is correct, but in an attempt to implement the MVVM pattern, I have created a model class 'Test' in the following way:

```
public class Test : BindableBase
{
    private int testNumber;
    public int TestNumber
    {
        get { return testNumber; }
        set { SetProperty(ref testNumber, value) }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then I created an instance of this class in my `ViewModel`:

```
class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Test testVM;
    public Test TestVM
    {
        get { return testVM; }
        set { SetProperty(ref testVM, value); }
    }
    ...
```

And in the XAML code of the `View` I bind all the properties of the `Test` class through the `TestVM` property. Although this works fine, I ran into a problem when trying to implement a `DelegateCommad`.

```
    public DelegateCommand StartTestCommand { get; private set; }
```

So far, when implementing `DelegateCommand`s, if I want to trigger the `CanExecute` method when a property has changed, I include `DelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` inside the property's setter. Like so:

```
    ...
    private bool duringTest;
    public bool DuringTest
    {
        get { return duringTest; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref duringTest, value);
            StartTestCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
    ...
```

This works fine for properties declared in the `ViewModel`, but when using the same approach for the `Test` properties, this no longer works.

```
    ...
    private Test testVM;
    public Test TestVM
    {
        get { return testVM; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref testVM, value);
            StartTestCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that every time a property from `TestVM` was changed, the setter would be called, but instead the model is updated directly.

**What am I doing wrong? What is the correct approach when using a `Model` object in the `ViewModel`?**

Comment: Would you please clarify how you are binding the TestVM property in XAML? Is it a TwoWay binding?

Comment: Not sure why you have to raise the `TestVM` notification when one of it's property changed? Do you have any specific requirement>?

Comment: @AlexRusskov Yes, it is TwoWay binding.

Comment: @user1672994 For example, I would like to run the CanExecute() method every time the TestVM.TestNumber property has been modified by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a property value of an object doesn't change the object's reference.

Declaring this

```
public Test TestVM
{
    get { return testVM; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref testVM, value);
        StartTestCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

you are basically telling the compiler: when the reference to the `TestVM` object is changed (even to the same value), update the `StartTestCommand`'s state.

But obviously you don't change the reference to that object once you assigned it.

If you want to update the commands in your parent view-model (`ViewModel`) when some child view-model's (`Test`) properties change, you can use the `PropertyChanged` event:

```
public Test TestVM
{
    get { return testVM; }
    set
    {
        Test oldValue = testVM;
        if (SetProperty(ref testVM, value))
        {
            if (oldValue != null)
            {
                oldValue.PropertyChanged -= TestPropertyChanged;
            }

            if (testVM!= null)
            {
                testVM.PropertyChanged += TestPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }
}

void TestPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // filter if necessary
    if (e.PropertyName == "...")
    {
        StartTestCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: "When the reference to the TestVM object is changed (even to the same value), update the StartTestCommand's state". So this means that the setter would be called if I wrote something like: TestVM = new Test();

Comment: You should also leave `StartTestCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` in the `TestVM` setter, otherwise initial and subsequent setting of `TestVM` won't invalidate the command.

Comment: @Grx70, that's up to the requirement. Maybe, there's no need to do that. But it's worth noting, thanks.